# Should reusable django apps use `zip_safe=False` in setup.py?

Tags: django, setup.py, egg

I am unsure if reusable django apps should use `zip_safe=False` in setup.py.

What does break if a django app does not specify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** The parameter `zip_safe=False` was important until Django 1.7.11, but since Django 1.8 it can be omitted. Django 1.7 has not been supported in mainstream since December 2015 and this parameter can be usually removed from applications setup now.

---

It was used due to `management/commands/*.py` and also data files like html templates, without relying on autodetection by setuptools. The opposite `zip_safe=True` was a fatal problem with `bdist_egg` command because management commands were not found in compressed installations.

The [zip_safe autodetection](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#setting-the-zip-safe-flag) by setuptools
could be correct sometimes only by accident because the presence of management commands is not being recognized. A small change in your code can cause that your app will be compressed by some versions of installers. The parameter zip_safe has been removed even from Django setup.py and added again for safety [in 2013](https://github.com/django/django/commit/929ceadda129090e260ec693178b992cd02da7bb).

Comment: I could not find more details to "The autodetection by setuptools". Do you know what kind of guessing happens here?

Comment: I added a link about zip_safe details to the answer. I remember that such issues are not early, maybe after hundred forks of some Django project, but awkward and not clear.

Comment: I read your answer like "yes, use zip_safe=False". The docs about reusable apps does not says so. I opened a ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26489

Comment: I checked the current Django. The parameter `zip_save` was necessary until Django 1.7.11 only, but since 1.8 it is not important and also management commands can be found in compressed installations.

Comment: We can wait it anybody knows about a problem in new versions, but it can be only a bug, not a feature.